# Inline interface implementation - Implement interface methods at declaration

Tags: php, oop, interface, declaration, implementation

I come from java, where we can do something like this:

Action.java:

```
public interface Action {
    public void performAction();
}
```

MainClass.java:

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) { //program entry point
        Action action = new Action() {

            public void performAction() {
                // custom implementation of the performAction method
            }

        };

        action.performAction(); //will execute the implemented method
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm not creating a class which implements `Action`, but I'm implementing the interface directly on declaration.

Is something like this even possible with PHP?

What I've tried:

action.php:

```
<?php

interface Action {

    public function performAction();
}

?>
```

myactions.php:

```
include "action.php";

$action = new Action() {

    public function performAction() {
        //do some stuff
    }
};
```

What I get:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in myactions.php on line 3
```

So, my question is: is something like this possible with PHP? How should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, can't. PHP doesn't offer anonymous classes like Java does. You can however try to simulate the behaviour you want, but the results will be...mixed at best.

Here's some code:

```
interface Action
{
    public function performAction();
}

class MyClass
{
    public function methodOne($object)
    {
        $object->performAction(); // can't call directly - fatal error

        // work around
        $closure = $object->performAction;
        $closure();
    }

    public function methodTwo(Action $object)
    {
        $object->performAction();
    }
}

$action = new stdClass();
$action->performAction = function() {
    echo 'Hello';
};

$test = new MyClass();
$test->methodOne($action); // will work
$test->methodTwo($action); // fatal error - parameter fails type hinting

var_dump(method_exists($action, 'performAction')); // false
var_dump(is_callable(array($action, 'performAction'))); // false
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 5):

With PHP 7, this has become possible with [anonymous classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php).

```
$action = new class implements Action() {
    public function performAction() {
        //do some stuff
    }
};
```